# can one do math on :properties:?

Tags: org-mode

I would like to use column-mode to create a project rollup similar to MSProject, but much simpler and faster. I would like to have a column for :hours:, and a column for :materials_cost:. Here's the core of my question: can I create a column for :total cost: which would be this math (I'm pretending I'd write it like this):

:total_cost: = :hours: * 210 + :materials_cost:.

this is sufficiently simple to do in excel or a org-table, but doesn't use the greatness of folding in outlines which column-mode allows, with the simplicity of sums {+}. I've searched everywhere for some mention about math with properties.

Answer (score 1):

Look at org-collector http://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/org-collector.html. This collects properties in a table, where you can then do calculations.